# How to exit an application, close all the activity and show the home screen?

Tags: android, android-intent, exit

I had wandered in the web for an hour and hour, I couldn't able find a code that closes my app completely and closes all activities then return to home screen.Even though "EXIT' button  is indispensable for an android app I couldn't find a perfect code for my job.I
 giving the codes didn't work.So please don't suggest that.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

> this code closes app and shows homescreen.But it didn't close running app.It simply minimises the app

```
Activity.finish();
System.exit(0);    

    protected void quit(){
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
}
```

> This code simply restarts the current activity

Comment: Have a look at the other answers in the linked "duplicate" question. There are many ways to do what you want, even though it is not usually done in Android. The easiest way is to launch your "root activity" using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and pass an "extra" telling the root `Activity` that you want to exit. This will clear all activities from the activity stack, and your root activity just needs to call `finish()` to exit.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

Or call `moveTaskToBack(true)` on your Activity instead of `System.exit()`. This will hide your application until the user wants to use it again.

Remember, as long as you're responding to lifecycle events appropriately, neither you nor the user needs to care if your application is still running or not.

So if you want to hide your application call `moveTaskToBack()` and let Android decide when to kill it.

Comment: let me try . Thanks for your response

Comment: It simply restart the current activity

Comment: I want to kill my app on button click

Comment: @abdul This is not how Android apps should work. The Android OS handles memory management and processes and so on so my advice is just let Android worry about this for you. If the user wants to leave your application they can press the Home button and your application will effectively disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I like to use `finishAndRemoveTask();` on my MainActivity, which removes the app from the recent apps and closes it completly. Or you can simply use `finishTask();` if you want your app to be on the recent apps screen.

Comment: please explain how to use finishAndRemoveTask(); and finishTask();

Comment: this" finishAndRemoveTask(); " restart the activity